# Redeclaring a C function in a linked library in C++

Tags: c++, linker

I'm trying to wrap my head around a linking issue that I'm dealing with. I'm writing a C++ library (libMFG.so), which links (statically, but it doesn't matter) another C library (libSpiS.a).

When I go to link to libMFG later in the build, I get unresolved symbol errors for the functions in libSpiS.a. My guess is because the symbols are mangled by c++.

I've tried:

#### Include the entire header for libSpiS.a under an `extern "C"{}`

This seems to have partially worked, but the headers included *within that header* then throw errors at compile time

#### Re-declare the functions in my cpp file

If I do this (under an `extern "C"{}` of course) *after* the header is included, I get a pretty clear error, however after reading a few questions on here, it looks like I'm supposed to declare it as C *before* it's redeclared (and assumed c++). However, that doesn't work because the function requires types that are only declared within the header.

The static library and header are shipped by a vendor. I'd strongly prefer not to modify them if possible, but it looks like I have to go into the header and add the `extern` there.

How am I supposed to link a C library to a C++ library/program?

Comment: Can you include a link to the libSpiS library you use?

Comment: I can't, it's a vendor proprietary library compiled for QNX so it's not something I can share

Comment: If I had a library that provided C headers which were not C++ savvy, I'd make my own C++ thunk headers that wrapped their library headers.  I'd have my own C++ code only use the C++ thunk headers, and not directly use the library C-only headers.

Comment: @Eljay are you suggesting to wrap their functions too? Or just redeclare the functions somehow?

Comment: If their spis/Foo.h header did `#include <stdio.h> struct bar; void foo(bar*);` I'd make my thunk SpisFoo.hpp header do `#include <cstdio> extern "C"{ #include <spis/Foo.h> }` (with header guards et cetera, just a stripped down example here).

Comment: @BrydonGibson Do you mean that you can't even share a link to the documentation? It's not this? https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.custom_bsp/topic/spi.html

Comment: There is no documentation unfortunately. It was provided as a binary blob. Any documentation (there is none, I've asked) is owned by the vendor and AFAIK there's nothing I can share publicly. Do the docs matter though? Any C static lib should behave the same

Comment: @Eljay I see what you mean. I'll give that a go and see if it does what I need

Comment: Depending on the SpiS header structure, it may be easiest to make one single all-encompassing thunk header for your C++ code to use, rather than a 1:1 mapping for the SpiS public consumption headers.  The common phrase "C++ is a superset of C" is not true, and I don't think it has ever been entirely true (maybe 100% true way back when C++ was called **C with Classes**).  You are experiencing how much C++ is not a superset of C right now.

Comment: _"There is no documentation unfortunately..."_ - I see the problem. What does the library contain? Is it a driver for the same vendors hardware?

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's correct. An undocumented blob and we got broken example code. I've got a C version working, but now there's a c++ api that I have to support

Comment: Nightmare ... Good thing there are most probably more serious suppliers around for the next project :-)

Comment: You'd think.. This was the most expensive and well known supplier out there. Unfortunately the silicon was chosen before the engineers came on board

Comment: I've been there ... I've also been in involved when choosing supplier a few times and if I don't see good documentation, it's a "no" from me.

Comment: What are the errors you see with `extern "C"`? Please show a [mre]

Comment: "looks like I have to go into the header and add the extern there" - if headers are simple enough this can be automated via simple `sed` command or `perl` script. Do not forget about `ifdef __cplusplus` to make header both C and C++-compatible.